# How to activate compatibility tab in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility

How to run program in compatibility mode in Windows 8? I have no "Compatibility" tab in my shortcut properties.

Comment: which program do you try to run? Internal Windows tool don't have compatibility tab.

Comment: `crysis.exe` (old Crysis game executable)

Comment: Try option 6 from this guide: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9564-run-administrator-windows-8-a.html

Comment: If that fails, go over this: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6832-compatibility-mode-use-windows-8-a.html

Comment: @sabrefresco sorry didn't understand why do you speak about "run as administrator"; is this related with run in compatibility mode?

Comment: @SuzanCioc I read on the EA forums that running Crysis as administrator sometimes helps with the crashes on Windows 8. If that does not work, try compatibility.

Comment: The Compatibility tab does not appear on 64-bit programs.

Answer (score 7):

Tested on Windows 10, 8.1, and 8.

- Right click on your program, and hit `Troubleshoot compatibility`.
- Wait for it to load, and hit the second option, `Troubleshoot
  program`.
- Check the third check box, `The program requires additional
  permissions`.
- Hit `Test the program...`. You have to in order to continue.
- Hit `Yes` and grant it administrator privileges.
- Now, exit out of the program and hit `Next` on the troubleshooter dialog.
- Hit `Yes, save these settings for this program`.
- You are done! Hit `Close`.